# Let be A and B finite sets. If $n(A)=n(B)$, then $n(B-A)=n(A-B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I need help with this exercise.

"Using the property of disjoint additivity solve the following problem. Let be A and B finite sets. If $n(A)=n(B)$, then $n(B-A)=n(A-B)$."

Looking for ways to do this I found that $n(A)=n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)$.

So,

$$n(A)=n(B)$$
$$n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)=n(B-A)+n(A\cap B)$$
$$n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)-n(A\cap B)=n(B-A)$$
$$n(A-B)=n(B-A)$$
$$n(B-A)=n(A-B)$$

Is this proof ok? If so, can someone help me to understand why $n(A)=n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)$?

Also, I never heard before about "property of disjoint additivity". I tried to look in the internet and I didn't found anything. Does it sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: I already understand why $n(A)=n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)$. By definition $A-B=\{x|x\in A ∧ x\notin B \}$, therefore $n(A-B)=n(A)-n(A \cap B)$. Solving for $n(A)$ we get $n(A)=n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)$. Anyway, is the proof ok?

Comment: You are spot on!

Comment: Using the same property of disjoint additivity, one could also argue that $n(A) + n(B-A) = n(A \cup B) = n(B) + n(A-B),$ whence $n(B-A) = n(A - B).$

Comment: You must use the finiteness of the sets. If $A=\mathbb Z$ and $B=\mathbb N$ then   $\lvert A-B\rvert$ is countable and $\lvert B-A\rvert$ is empty.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$A=A\cap \mathcal U=A\cap (B\cup B^\complement)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^\complement)$$
where $\mathcal U$ is the universe, $(A\cap B)$ and $(A\cap B^\complement)=A-B$ are disjoint. Therefore,
$$n(A)=n(A\cap B)+n(A-B)$$

The property of disjoint additivity is just saying that if you partition a set $A$ into two disjoint parts $A_1,A_2$, then the number of elements in $A$ is equal to the number of elements in $A_1$ plus the number of elements in $A_2$. This is true not only for finite sets but for any set

$$|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|,\text{ if } A \cap B = \emptyset$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality.

Comment: What if $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb N$?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ are not disjoint, but still $|\mathbb Q|+|\mathbb N|=\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

Comment: $\mathbb N -\mathbb Q$ is empty. What is the other difference?

Comment: Cardinal subtraction is not defined in this way. [Assuming the axiom of choice and, given an infinite cardinal $σ$ and a cardinal $μ$, there exists a cardinal $κ$ such that $μ + κ = σ$ if and only if $μ ≤ σ$. It will be unique (and equal to $σ$) if and only if $μ < σ$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number)

Comment: Have I misunderstood the question? The theorem is talking about the cardinality of the set difference, not the difference of two cardinals. The point is that the cardinalities of the two differences are not equal. We need to use the finiteness as in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: $n(B-A)=n(A-B)$ is true only with finite sets because the subtraction step in the question would be invalid if the sets are infinite. My answer is mainly trying to explain why $n(A)=n(A-B)+n(A\cap B)$, which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

---

> If so, can someone help me to understand why n(A)=n(A−B)+n(A∩B)

---

Let's take a look on what is A-B :-

*[A-B = All the elements of A excluding those which are common in both A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NIX8.png)*

So by the definition :- (A-B) = A - (A∩B)

Rearranging the terms :-

[**set A = (A-B) + (A∩B)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKqYD.png)

n(set A) = n[(A-B) + (A∩B)]

n(set A) = n(A-B) + n(A∩B)

**Note :-** last step n(C+D) = n(C) + n(D), where C = (A-B) and D = (A∩B) is only valid if both sets are disjoint (Intersection of both the sets must be a null set) and we can apply it here because (A-B) and (A∩B) are disjoint. Actual formula is n(C+D) = n(C) + n(D) - n(C∩D )